# Transfer file between iPhones using wifi in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, wifi

I am working on a project where I need to connect 2 or more iPhones and transfer files between those using Wifi hotspot. Kindly advice any way to achieve this or any sample code where we can do this. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried Dropbox api ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `multipeer connctivity`

you should refer [Appcoda's grate tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-ios-multipeer-connectivity-programming/)

or

You should refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577630/transfer-file-from-one-ios-device-to-another-using-wifi-and-3g-network) and refer every link given in accepted answer of this question. your problem will be resolved.

Hope this will help :)